# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, local-storage, underscore.js

I have the following in the backbonejs app:

```
////MODEL
var app={};
app.ledger=Backbone.Model.extend();

////COLLECTION
app.ledgerList=Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: app.ledger,
localStorage:new Store('ledgerstore')
 });

////INITIATING COLLECTION
app.ledgerlist=new app.ledgerList();
```

In one of my views i try to create a new model in the collection like this:

```
newAttributes:function(){
    return{
        name:$("#ledgerName").val(),
        email: $("#ledgerEmail").val(),
        address: $("#ledgerAddress").val(),
        phone: $("#ledgerPhone").val()

     }},
saveLedger: function(){
    app.ledgerlist.create(this.newAttributes());


}
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined` on the line `app.ledgerlist.create(this.newAttributes());`

It all started occuring suddenly out of nowhere. It was working a few mins back. I guess it has to do something with localstorage. I cleared it but still the same. In firefox console says d.collection is undefined.

Please guide.

Comment: So you got [unable to use create method on collections in backbonejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422433/unable-to-use-create-method-on-collections-in-backbonejs) working? The error seems to appear in exactly the same line

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595316/backbone-js-and-localstorage-plugin-relation-between-collection-and-model-bas

Comment: @RachelGallen somewhat a different issue in the link you pointed.

Comment: So is this resolved ... ?

Comment: Where does `Store()` come from? / what localstorage plugin are you using?  https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage ?